# SharePoint list send email programatically

Tags: list

I have this code for SPUtility but i don't know where to put it to send an email from my form the form includes text box to insert an email from active directory but I want the code to send an message to that email

```
if (!SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(currentWeb))
{
    SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("Please configure the outgoing e-mail settings in Central Administration")
}
```

Comment: you want to use this code to send an email?

Comment: yes i want to use this code

Answer (score 1):

To send email from SharePoint, you can use [SPUtility.SendEmail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms463202%28v=office.15%29) or configure 'Send Email' workflow using SharePoint designer. You need to ensure that the outgoing e-mail settings are configured in Central Administration.

If you have a custom webpart or form, you can also use *SmtpClient* from ASP.NET to send emails. [Here is an example.](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx)

Comment: the workflow is not working that's why i want to use the sputility i just need to now where i should put this code exactly because i tried to put it inside form.aspx but thinks it should be written in another place

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the form you have is a list form, you can create an event receiver on item adding event, and write the sputility code to send email to the person present in the field inside that event. So when the users is adding and item and he saves an email will get generated.

Answer (score 0):

I published a similar solution a while back. http://sharepointa1a.codeplex.com/